# Wordpress theme: Admin bar blank on front end

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a new Wordpress theme. The admin bar appears on the front end, but is blank. On the backend, the admin bar is present and correct, and I can amend it by adding the relevant statements into functions.php. I imagine I have overlooked something obvious - there is no problem with the admin bar, when I change to another theme, but as soon as I use the theme that I am developing, the front end admin bar goes blank.

Can anyone point me to a possible solution? This is the first theme that I have written from scratch - previous themes have all been based on the Quark theme, which, in turn, uses _s. Everything else I want to do with the theme is working well, but not the frontend admin bar - which exists, but is a blank black bar.

Comment: Without seeing your code, or any part of your theme, it will be near impossible to get a reliable answer .. I suggest adding as much *pertinent* detail as possible, including code, snippets etc.

Comment: I am going back now, to copy some of my functions here for you to look at. But, in the meantime, is there a specific function call that causes the admin menus to display, that _s contains, but that I may have forgotten in this new theme?  I might have to post my entire functions.php file if no such function call exists.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - just for completeness. I have found the answer to my own question. Research elsewhere showed me that the code that displays the admin menus is contained in the function wp_footer(). So all I needed to do was add

```
<?php
wp_footer();
?>
```

to the bottom of my footer.php file.